# How can I add string value and integer value into listbox in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I'm beginner for **vb.net**.I try to add string value and integer value into **listbox** but it throw invalid cast exception.I mention code bellow.

```
Public Class frmDetails

        Private Sub btnCompute_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCompute.Click
            Listbox1.Items.Add("sum is " + (3 + 2))
            Listbox1.Items.Add("Substract is" + (3 - 2))
            Listbox1.Items.Add("Multiplication is " + (3 * 2))
            Listbox1.Items.Add("Division is " + (3 / 2))
            Listbox1.Items.Add("3 to power 2  " + (3 ^ 2))
        End Sub

        Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
            Dispose()
        End Sub
    End Class
```

[image]

please help me to solve this.

Comment: If that code compiles, you need to turn on `Option Strict`

Comment: You should know that saying _it doesn't work_ it is the most useless thing to say in this site. Please specify exactly the error message received

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `&` for concatenating strings. Then use the `ToString` method for the equation.

```
 Listbox1.Items.Add("sum is " & (3 + 2).ToString)
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you are adding a `string` you need to add the `int` as a `string` like this:

```
Listbox1.Items.Add("sum is " & (3 + 2).ToString())
```

Every type has a ToString() function, the math operation 3 + 2 implicitly creates an integer type, you simply need to convert it.

Comment: VB.net uses the & operator for string concatenation usually.

Comment: `Listbox1.Items.Add("sum is " + (3 + 2).ToString())`  this code is also working

Comment: Yes, it does work at times, but `&` is more correct. @amilaisura